# Wheres the color setting for this footer txt?

Tags: html, css, colors, web

Im working on my Local Bike Shops site and cant find the footer text color to set it to something legible.

Its either in one of these or I need to add it to something. Im just not sure where to add and what.

Im a designer, so kinda learning this on the side project. Thanks!

INDEX

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Cupertino Bike Shop</title>
<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="320daddfb1db04c06e2fa1da259bee4d"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="Cupertino Bike Shop selling professional grade bicycles, parts, and tools" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Cervelo,Bike Shop, Bicycle Shop, Bicycles, Bikes, Road Bikes, Mountain Bikes, Mtn Bikes, bike tools, bike parts, cycles, cyclists, cupertino bike shop, professional bikes, pro bikes, Bay Area bike shop, Specialized, Easton, Campagnolo" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.cupertinobikeshop.com/images/cbsfavicon.png">

<meta name="robots" content="all" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cuperstyles.css" type="text/css" />



</head>

<body><a name="top" id="top"></a>
<div id="wrapper">
<br />
<br />

<table  width="647" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td width="292" valign="top">


    

<!--#include file="ssi/leftnav.html" -->
    </td><td width="647" valign="top">

<div id="content">
  <p>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="547" height="427" id="billboard_101607" align="middle">
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
      <param name="movie" value="billboard_101607.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
      <embed src="billboard_101607.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#cae4f9" width="621" height="427" name="billboard_101607" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />    
      </embed>
    </object>
   <p>
   <h2>2016 ANNUAL SWAP MEET!</h2></p>
  <p>Sunday April 24th 9 am to 4 pm<br />
    10625 S Foothill Blvd.<br />
    Cupertino CA 95014<br />
    408-255-2217<br />
    <br />
    Call the shop and reserve your space, $60<br />
    <br />
    Cash, check or PayPal (<a href="mailto:sprocket@gmail.com" target="_blank">&nbsp;vsprocket@gmail.com</a> )</p>
    
 
<h2>Cupertino Bike Shop</h2>
  <p>Are you considering buying a new bicycle? One of your first choices, and not necessarily an easy one, will be where to shop. It can be challenging because there are quite a variety of stores that carry two-wheelers, ranging from specialty retailers to giant department stores.</p>

<p>Where you buy, however, has everything to do with what you get. Bicycles aren't like toasters or suitcases; bikes are shipped in boxes and they must be assembled and tuned for optimal performance.</p>

<p>There are many types as well, and you should never buy until you've figured out which bicycle is right for you. Measurements and adjustments are required to ensure the frame is the correct size and that the seat and handlebars are properly positioned. And, every new bicycle will need a minor tune-up after several weeks as you break the bicycle in with normal use.</p>

<p>What's more, modern road and mountain bikes can travel at high speeds and carry you over demanding terrain where the machine's materials and construction get tested. A quality two-wheeler, carefully assembled and fit exactly to you, will be the safest, most durable, and most enjoyable bicycle you ride.</p>

<p>For these reasons, we strongly recommend shopping at a reputable specialty bicycle store like Cupertino Bike Shop. We employ competent salespeople and expert mechanics who'll ensure that you get the right bicycle and components for you. Our store is clean, friendly, offers a wide selection, and boasts one of the best on-site repair departments in the Bay Area.
</p>
  
    <h3>Bicycle Exchange </h3>
    <p>We accept bicycles to be repaired by <a href="http://svbcbikes.org" target="_blank">Silicon
      Valley Bicycle Coalition  </a>and given to needy
      families. <a href="http://svbcbikes.org/bicycle-exchange" target="_blank">More
      Information. </a><br />
    </p>
<h3>Road ID </h3>
    <p><a href="http://www.svtriclub.org/">Silicon
        Valley Triathlon Club</a> has teamed up with
        Road ID (the leader in safety identification
        and reflective gear for endurance athletes)
        to make sure our members are safer while training
        and competing.</p>
    <p>You can get more information about this Road
      ID Fundraiser Challenge program at the following
      URL: <a href="http://www.svtriclub.org/events/roadid.htm" target="_blank">http://www.svtriclub.org/events/roadid.htm</a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div align="center"><a href="#top">top</a></div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
<!--#include file="ssi/footer.html" -->
</div>
</td></tr>
</table> 
</div>


<br />
<br />
<br />


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```html
 /*  General styles below */
 
html { 
 SCROLLBAR-FACE-COLOR: #cecfce;
    SCROLLBAR-HIGHLIGHT-COLOR: #F2F9FF;
    SCROLLBAR-SHADOW-COLOR: #a6a6a6;
    SCROLLBAR-3DLIGHT-COLOR: #a6a6a6;
    SCROLLBAR-ARROW-COLOR: #F2F9FF;
    SCROLLBAR-TRACK-COLOR: #a6a6a6;
    SCROLLBAR-DARKSHADOW-COLOR: #C1C7CB;
}
/* Primary layout divisions */ 
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11px;
 text-align: center; 
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 color: #000;
}
#wrapper {
 <!--float: left;-->
 <!--width: 805px;-->
 text-align: left;
 max-width: 956px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 <!--padding: 0;-->
 border-right: 15px solid #767676;
 background-image: url(../images/bkgs/bg_columnLayout.gif);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#navWrap {
 float: left;
 width: 292px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 
}

.imgblk{border: #000000 solid 4px; padding: 0}
.imgblk2{border: #000000 solid 2px; padding: 0}
.imgwht{border: #ffffff inset 4px; padding: 0}
#content {
 width: 625px; 
 padding: 12px;
}
p {
 margin: 0 0 15px 0; text-align: left;
}

img {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
 
 /* Default links  */
 
a:link {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #6699cc;
}
a:visited {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #336699;
}

a:hover {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #224466;
 text-decoration: underline; 
 }
a:active {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #6699cc;
}

 /* Typography  */
 
h2 {
 font: normal 20px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
 border-bottom: #000; 
 border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; 
 border-style: none none dotted none;
 }

h3 {
 font: normal 18px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 0.15em;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
 }

h4 {
 font: bold 16px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #F36;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
 }
 
h5 {
 font: bold 12px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 5px;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
 }
 
h6 {
 font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


#content{
text-align:left
}

.image-container a img{
 width: 100%;
}

.an-image,
.image-container,
.image-container a{
 height: auto !important;
 max-height: none !important;
}


#footer {
 clear: both;
 border: 0;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 color: #f5f5f5;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 width: 564;
 float: left;
font-size:9px; 
font-weight: bold;
 
 }
 
#footer a:link {
 color: #f5f5f5;
}
 


#footer ul, li{
 font-size: 110%;
 display: inline; 
 padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
}

#nav {
float: left;
background-color:#f5f5f5;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 25px;
text-align:left;
width: 292px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px;  
font-weight: bold; 
}

#nav a:link{
text-transform: uppercase; 
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px; 
color:#5b5b5b; 
font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;  
}

#nav a:visited{ 
color: #5b5b5b; 
text-decoration:none; 
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav a:hover{ 
color: #000; 
text-decoration:none; 
text-transform: uppercase; 

background-image: url(images/bkgs/nav_arrow.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position:left; 
}

#nav a:visited{ color: #5b5b5b; text-decoration:underline; text-transform: uppercase;}

 /* NAV Dividers  */


#hr {
   display: line;
   color: #f5f5f5; 
   margin: 10px 0;
}

#footer{
  width:100%;
  bottom:1;
  left:0;
}
```

LEFTNAV

```html
 <div align="left">
 <img src="images/5stripe.jpg" alt="Cupertino Bike Shop" width="302" height="30" /><br />
 <br />
 <br />
</div>

 <div align="center">
<img src="images/logo_cbs.gif" alt="Cupertino Bike Shop" />
<br />
<br />
</div> 


<div id="nav"> 

<div id="address" align="center" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#5b5b5b;margin-top: 10px;"> 
<p>HOURS<br />
  Monday Closed<br />
  Tuesday-Friday 11-7<br />
  Saturday 10-5<br />
  Sunday 12-5 (Closed Dec, Jan, Feb)<br />
  </p>
<p>
10625 S. Foothill Blvd.<br />
Cupertino, CA 95014<br />
(408) 255-2217<br /></div>
  
  <!-- BEGIN: Constant Contact Email List Form Button -->
<div align="center"><a href="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp?llr=lr7tsdpab&p=oi&m=1115737944619&sit=wsxo6akib&f=32f0b20f-f220-4402-a29a-ef33281fd4fc" class="button" style="background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232); border: 1px solid rgb(91, 91, 91); color: #5b5b5b; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 10px; text-shadow: none; border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;">Subscribe Now</a><!-- BEGIN: Email Marketing you can trust --><div id="ctct_button_footer" align="center" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:10px;color:#5b5b5b;margin-top: 10px;">Get our latest news</div></div>
            
  
  
</p>
<br />
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FCupertino-Bike-Shop%2F113664399772&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=62" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"><br /></iframe>
<p></p>
<br /><a href="index.html">Home</a><br /><hr />
<br />
<a href="sale09.html">Daisy's Dynamic Deals</a><br /><hr />
<br />
<a href="classic.html">Classic Corner</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="shop.html">Cool Things to Buy </a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="BikeLines.html">Bike Lines </a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="ProductLines.html">Product Lines </a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="rides.html">Rides</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="tech.html">Tech Support</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="swapmeet.html">Annual Bike Swap</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="history.html">History</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="teams.html">Teams We Support</a><br /><hr />
<br /><a href="videos.html">Videos & Other Fun Things</a><br />
<p></p>
</div>
```

FOOTER

```html
<div id="footer">

<ul>
<li>
  ©<script language = 'JavaScript' type="text/javascript">
<!--
function y2k(number) { return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number; }
var today = new Date();
var year = y2k(today.getYear());
document.write(+year);
//-->
</script> Cupertino Bike Shop</li>
<li>10625 S. Foothill Boulevard, Cupertino, CA 95014</li>
<li>(408) 255-2217</li>
<li><a href="mailto:sprocket@cupertinobikeshop.com">sprocket@cupertinobikeshop.com</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: No one is going to read all this. Just make a small snippet targeting problem you want to solve.

Comment: Just use your developer tools. Right-click the text, hit Inspect Element, then read the applied CSS styles.

Answer (score 2):

Your current footer's text color is #f5f5f5, as stated in your CSS file. Change that to a different color code and you will have a different text color in your footer.

Quoting your code:

> ```
> #footer {
>     clear: both;
>     border: 0;
>     background-color: #cccccc;
>     color: #f5f5f5;
>     padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
>     margin: 0;
>     font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
>     width: 564;
>     float: left;
>     font-size: 9px; 
>     font-weight: bold;
> }
>
> #footer a:link {
>     color: #f5f5f5;
> }
> ```

Tip: You can easily find these elements using your browser's developer tools (Right Click -> Inspect Element).

Comment: Ha! Totallly missed it because I thought that code stood for darker grey than white grey.